# Split the combine data(Numeric and Sting) to separate data

Tags: sql

How can i split string data 'Test123' to two columns 'Test' and '123'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132734/getting-a-certain-part-of-the-string-in-t-sql "Getting a certain part of the string in T-SQL") is similar. Although it asks about a string where the text part has a fixed length, most suggestions disregard that and thus can be equally applied to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created below function for this, Please update here if there is any other simple method

```
/*
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SPLIT_NUMERIC_STRING] ('TEST1235745DFGBFVNYT HGEFNEYGV  @ADBSD H# CHSC5ae23674523')
*/
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SPLIT_NUMERIC_STRING] 
   (  @ColumnName VARCHAR(MAX)
   ) 
   RETURNS @TABLEOFVALUES TABLE 
      (  NUMERICDATA   VARCHAR(MAX), 
         STRINGDATA VARCHAR(MAX) 
      ) 
AS 
   BEGIN

        DECLARE @Column1 VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @Column2 VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @StartPosition INT
        DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @NUMBER INT
        DECLARE @ENDPosition INT
        SET @Column1 = ''
        SET @Column2 = ''
        SET @StartPosition = 1

        SELECT @ENDPosition =  LEN(@ColumnName)

        WHILE @ENDPosition > 0 
        BEGIN

            SELECT @String = SUBSTRING(@ColumnName,@StartPosition,1)
            SELECT @NUMBER = ISNUMERIC(@String)

            IF (@NUMBER = 1)
            BEGIN
             SET @Column1 = @Column1 + @String
            END 
            ELSE
             SET @Column2 = @Column2 + @String 

            SET @StartPosition = @StartPosition + 1
            SET @ENDPosition = @ENDPosition - 1
        END
        INSERT INTO @TABLEOFVALUES (NUMERICDATA,STRINGDATA)
        SELECT @Column1 AS NUMERICDATA,@Column2 AS STRINGDATA

      RETURN 

   END
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

1. build functionality so you can use Regular Expressions directly in Sql. Example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42764/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-SQL-Server-2005-2008
2. use substring
3. if the length of letters vs digits is not fixed you may also use a WHILE loop for example and grab one character after another after you find a digit